# How To Get The Index and Caption of a ActionClient ChildItem Added At RunTime

Tags: delphi

This adds an ActionClientItem at runtime from a stringList:

```
var
  ActionClient: TActionClient;
  ChildItem: TActionClientItem;
if FileExists( ARecentFilesFilename ) then
begin
  ARecentFilesList.LoadFromFile( ARecentFilesFilename );
  // remove any duplicates
  RemoveDuplicates( ARecentFilesList );
  for i := 0 to ARecentFilesList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Ribbon1.AddRecentItem( ARecentFilesList.Strings[ i ] );
      ActionClient := RibbonGroup1.ActionControls[ 1 ].ActionClient;
      ChildItem := ActionClient.Items.Add;
      ChildItem.Tag := i;
      ChildItem.Action := ActionOpenFileFromButton1;
      ChildItem.Caption := ARecentFilesList.Strings[ i ];
    end;
end;
```

This attempts to get the filename of the selected ActionClientItem but it fails.

```
procedure TMainForm.ActionOpenFileFromButton1Execute( Sender: TObject );
var
  ActionClient: TActionClient;
  ChildItem: TActionClientItem;
  AFilename: string;
  AIndex: integer;
begin
  ActionClient := RibbonGroup1.ActionControls[ 1 ].ActionClient;
  AIndex := ActionClient.Index;
  ChildItem := ActionClient.Items.ActionClients[ AIndex ];
  AFilename := ChildItem.Caption;
  OpenZipFileFromChildButton( AFilename );
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a different way do do this?

Comment: "It fails" is not sufficient description of the problem. Does it not compile? Does it give you a result you didn't expect? Does it crash? Does it make your printer catch fire? If yes to any of those, then tell us the error message or send a photo of the printer.

Comment: AIndex returns the incorrect indexbecause it always returns "1".  I think it is returning the index of the ActionClient and not the TActionClientItem.... How do you get the index of the TActionClientItem?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be the index of the ActionClient? You're assigning it by reading `ActionClient.Index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Sender` to get access to the filename, but it's a `TAction`, so you need to have one action per recent file. Add them to your ActionManager and also keep a reference to them in a list.

**edit**

If you don't have a `TActionManager` on your form, drop one on there and associate it with the ribbon. Then, create say 10 actions, calling them RecentFileAction1, RecentFileAction2, etc. Then, in the form's `OnCreate` event handler, add them to your `FRecentFileActions` list:

```
TMainForm = class (TForm)

  //...

private
  FRecentFileActions: TList<TAction>;

  //...

end;


procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(ASender: TOject);
begin
  FRecentFileActions := TList<TAction>.Create;

  FRecentFileActions.Add(RecentFileAction1);
  FRecentFileActions.Add(RecentFileAction2);
  FRecentFileActions.Add(RecentFileAction3);
  // etc

  LoadRecentFilenames;
  RefreshActions;

end;
```

**/edit**

Then, change the caption on each action to the filename of the file.

```
procedure TMainForm.RefreshActions;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to FRecentFileList.Count - 1 do
  begin     
    if i < FRecentFileActions.Count then
      FRecentFileActions[i].Caption := FRecentFileList[i];
  end;
end;
```

So, in the end, your event handler could look like this:

```
procedure TMainForm.ActionOpenFileFromButton1Execute( Sender: TObject );
var
  LAction: TAction;
begin
  LAction := Sender as TAction;
  OpenZipFileFromChildButton(LAction.Caption);
end;
```

N@

Comment: +1 Definitely the way to go. I may create a TMRUAction or something like that, that keeps the full file path in a property, but your basic strategy is spot-on.

Comment: After spending a second full day on this I still can not get the index or caption of the selected action in my demo.  if FRecentFileActions is a TAction you can not interate through it because TAction only has one caption per action. Do you have to use an Actionlist or the ActionManager to do this?
if i < FRecentFileActions.Count then      
  FRecentFileActions[i].Caption := FRecentFileList[i];
My demo is a simple D2010 project with only vcl components.  If you are interested in assisting me, can I email you my demo?

Bill

Comment: Yes, you need an ActionManager or a ActionList. I assumed you had an ActionManager since you seemed to be using a Ribbon. See my new edit at the top of my answer.

Comment: Yes I have an ActionManager... but sorry...:
var
FRecentFileActions: TAction;
procedure TMainForm.RefreshActions;
var  i: integer;
begin  
  for i := 0 to FRecentFileList.Count - 1 do  
  begin         
    if i < FRecentFileActions.Count then      
      FRecentFileActions[i].Caption := FRecentFileList[i];  
  end;
end;

will not even compile if FRecentFileActions is a TAction.  There must be more variables defined for this to compile.

Comment: FRecentFileActions is not a TAction. It is a Generic TList<T>, instantiated as a list of TActions... So it is "FRecentFileActions: TList<TAction>", exactly as I typed in my answer. You have to have Generics.Collections in your uses clause.